# primeNG p-dropdown stretch 100%

Tags: css, primeng

How to set the **primeNG** dropdown width to stretch 100% inside its container?

It seems to have fixed **element.style** and the **.ui-dropdown{ width: 100% }** override
does not work.

Comment: do you mean primeNG?

Answer (score 54):

In my case I used autoWidth = false and set style attrribute like below

```
<p-dropdown [options]="educationLevels" [(ngModel)]="selectedEducationLevel" 
name="educationlevel" autoWidth="false" [style]="{'width':'100%'}"></p-dropdown>
```

Comment: This works for me without autoWidth="false"

Comment: @UrbanoJVR .. can you please post your answer...

Answer (score 36):

I found to use the Responsive approach and apply **.ui-fluid** style with Grid CSS at container while **p-dropdown** should have the **[autoWidth]="false"** attribute.

Example:

```
<div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-fluid">
    <div class="ui-grid-row">
        <div class="ui-grid-col-12">
            <p-dropdown [autoWidth]="false"></p-dropdown>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, that saved me ton of time! I already had .ui-fluid in the form and my `p-dropdown` was always 30px wide. Setting `autoWidth` to false fixed the problem.

Comment: @Episodex Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

For me,

> [style]="{'minWidth':'100%'}"

does the trick!

Then I used like this:

```
<span style="width: 100%">
   <p-dropdown [style]="{'minWidth':'100%'}" [options]="items" [(ngModel)]="selecteditem"></p-dropdown>
</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this

html:

```
<div class="p-col-10">
  <span class="p-fluid">
    <p-dropdown></p-dropdown>
  </span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.p-dropdown-panel {
  left: 0 !important;
  max-width: 100% !important;
}
.p-autocomplete-panel .p-autocomplete-items .p-autocomplete-item {
  white-space: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [autoWidth] attr was removed in v7 but I was able to achieve this with >7 version using styleClass="w-100":
<p-dropdown styleClass="w-100" ...>

Answer (score 0):

You should be writing in a css file using the mentioned class as below,

```
.ui-dropdown    {
  width:100% !important;
}
```

Set it to be  `!important`

**[LIVE DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/SGnrtIAC8neDAm4np1ua?p=preview)**

Comment: Note: In my case, this needed to be applied under the global "styles.scss" rather than individual component stylesheets

Comment: Use specificity, not `!important`

Answer (score 0):

You should be editing a class in a primeng.min.css file as below,

```css
.ui-dropdown .ui-dropdown-panel {
  min-width: 100%;
  width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<p-dropdown id="id" [options]="list"></p-dropdown>
```

then Dropdownlist should take size of biggest option.

Answer (score 0):

For me:

```css
.ui-dropdown {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Did the trick, here is my html:

```html
<p-dropdown
  [options]="sitBusinessPartner"
  [filter]="true"
  [(ngModel)]="businessPartner"
  (onChange)="changeBusinessPartner()"
  [autoWidth]="false"
></p-dropdown>
```

Edit, I suggest to use this:

```css
.ui-dropdown.ui-dropdown-clearable .ui-dropdown-label {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.ui-dropdown .ui-dropdown-label {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

In order to handle a possible text overflow and display a nice ellipsis like this:

[image: Example of text overflow handling o]

This solution was adapted from [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/8785#issuecomment-640004713).

Answer (score 0):

What I did and worked for me:

Using the grid system you can choose how many "columns" to display the element. For example, if you want to stretch 100% inside the container, consider that the element is occupying 12 columns, like in the code below:

```
<div class="p-formgrid p-grid">
        <div class="p-field p-col">
            <p-dropdown></p-dropdown>
        </div>
</div>
```

But let's say you want to put another element next to it and want them to have the same width, you'd have something like that:

```
<div class="p-formgrid p-grid">
        <div class="p-field p-col">
            <p-dropdown></p-dropdown>
        </div>
        <div class="p-field p-col">
            <element></element>
        </div>
</div>
```

You can also have different widths for each element, based on how many columns they are occupying:

```
<div class="p-formgrid p-grid">
        <div class="p-field p-col-7">
            <p-dropdown></p-dropdown>
        </div>
        <div class="p-field p-col">
            <element></element>
        </div>
</div>
```

The sum of the columns has to be 12. If you said the first element is 7 columns long, the second will get 5 columns automatically. Try different values and see what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

For me, using prime-ng dropdown with template in grid, container that hold p-dropdown was `flex` so this both combined worked
`[className]="'col-12 p-0'"` and `[styleClass]="'col-12 p-0'"` added into `p-dropdown` tag

Answer (score -1):

"autoWidth" did not work for me, I just did this in my CSS:

```
p-dropdown {
    min-width: 80%;
}
.ui-dropdown{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Using element name `p-dropdown` will not affect the dropdown. You need to study more about angular css

Comment: The reason it doesn't affect the width has nothing to do with angular and has everything to do with selecting the correct element.

Answer (score -1):

Try this in css file.

```
:host ::ng-deep .p-dropdown {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **:host** and **::ng-deep** in your component **css** or **scss** file:

```
:host ::ng-deep.p-dropdown {
    width: 255px !important;
    height: 28px !important;
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.