# DropDown overlaps margin

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I have a problem with DropDown in Angular & Primeng. The DropDown with "style=width:100%" overlaps the border by selected large text.
The width size of then control should not depend on the text length.

An example can find at https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vur22c-cwrvzc

Have somebody a workaround?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [primeNG p-dropdown stretch 100%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41354416/primeng-p-dropdown-stretch-100)

Answer (score 0):

p-dropdown component has style property use that to set p-dropdown width.

**Try this:**

```
<h3>Test</h3>
<div style="width: 250px; height: 100px; padding: 20px; background-color: red">
  <p-dropdown [style]="{'width':'100%'}" [options]="options1" [(ngModel)]="selected1"></p-dropdown>
</div>
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-vur22c-cwrvzc)

Answer (score 0):

> The width size of then control should not depend on the text length.

This should do the trick.
Set on first div (the dropdown itself):

```
p-dropdown > div
```

or

```
 p-dropdown .ui-dropdown
```

*its the same selector, its up to you which one to use :))*

this css properties:

```
position: relative;
width: 100%;
```

p-dropdown is more like a directive/component and everything inside it is the elements that you are looking for.